# CSS: Leaflet markers borders stay displayed as undesirable effect

Tags: css, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

After have changed marker icon (same as original, just colorized), borders are still displayed under Firefox, not from Chromium :

[image: you can see]

This CSS code has no effect:

```
border: none; / border: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

An idea to force hide this undesirable effect?

Comment: It can be `box-shadow` or `outline`, not only border. Did you try changing any of these?

Comment: [Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please. show us that modified image file.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, this effect has added by an outside element: `.leaflet-pane.leaflet-shadow-pane` ; no rule applied on `.leaflet-pane.leaflet-marker-pane` that contain markers.
Code inspection has been not easy: [element to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRTTb.jpg)

Solved by simple `display: none;` rule on this element `.leaflet-pane.leaflet-shadow-pane`: [you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hd6q.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Seems rather like the "border" you see is actually the placeholder for a broken image.

Typically if your custom Marker icon's shadow is missing (e.g. you forgot to change its default value, while not providing the default shadow image asset)

This would also explain the different behaviour between browsers, since each of them hints for broken image differently.

Comment: Maybe, but nothing like that for an possible shadow image: `.leaflet-default-icon-path {
    background-image: url(images/marker-icon.png); }` (this is only one in all default leaflet.css)

Comment: You are fooled by Leaflet default icon image path automatic generation. See https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#icon-default and https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#icon

Comment: Humm, I will try this... Thanks!